# What do people mean when they say a function is “linear” or “non-linear”

Tags: modeling, stochastic-processes, nonlinear

It seems like every function/process can be "linear" given the right basis. e.g. the function x**2 is linear in the state space which includes polynomials of degree 1 to n. Similarly, a process like exponential growth appears non-linear in the sense that if I plot Y = a* exp(r * x), the line is curvy; however, the same plot looks "linear" if I plot it on a log axis.

A lot of people talk about something being linear or non-linear, and I'm not sure what this really means.

On a terminology note, is there such a difference between a linear/nonlinear "process" and a linear/nonlinear "function", or can function/process be used interchangeably in this context?

Comment: Does [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71437/distinction-between-linear-and-nonlinear-model/71444#71444) cover it? If not, could you clarify your question so as to make clear what you want to know that isn't covered there?